# How to verify that lyrics sync properly with song using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, synchronization

How can we verify that lyric of any song sync. properly, which displayed in video player as subtitle?

Also, lyrics get highlighted correctly in subtitle in the way song were sung using selenium webdriver.

Reference [link](http://www.vagalume.com.br/katy-perry/dark-horse-feat-juicy-j-traducao.html) for verifying the subtitle.

Comment: I think it's kind of impossible to do with Selenium.

Comment: Selenium can't see inside of a video playing without some additional libraries, if they even exist. You would also have to process the sounds and turn it into text to compare to the subtitles. I don't think this is something you are going to be able to do.

Comment: @JeffC is there any alternative way to to find the exact synchronization ?